# Determine the local minimum, local maximum, and inflection points for the functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to solve this question in matlab but i’m having some trouble to solve the question.

Here is the question:
Determine the local minimum, local maximum, and inflection points for the functions

Here is the function
[image]

Here is my matlab script

```
syms [x1,x2]

f = 3*x1.^2+2*x1.*x2+2*x2.^2+7;

G = gradient(f,[x1,x2]);

S = solve(G(1),G(2));

[S.x1 S.x2]

%settting gradient to zero givens x=(0, 0) as the only candidate minimum point

H = hessian(f,[x1,x2])
```

when I run the script I get this
[image]

and it feels like something is wrong
Someone who can help me with this?

Comment: "it feels like something is wrong". Science and maths don't really function with feelings. Can you elaborate

Comment: Because when run the script , I do not get a graph or what the gradient will be.So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The script outputs exactly the values you indicated it should output (the lines that don't end in a semicolon are the ones that print a result). You don't have code for plotting a graph, so you get no graph plotted. I am not sure what exactly you expected to happen, or what your question is. Please [edit] your post to make it more explicit about what a useful answer would look like.

Comment: How can I determine the local minimum, local maximum, and inflection points for the functions in my script?

Comment: I think fmincon command help you.

Comment: The information you really need is the relationship between gradient, hassien matrix, minumum/maximum and inflection point. First solve the problem with calculus by hand, then you know what result should you expect and what's really wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fmincon` command for finding the minimum of a function:

```
clc
clear
close all
x0 = [10 -10];
[x, fval]=fmincon(@myFunc1, x0)
function result = myFunc1(x) 
    result = 3*x(1)^2+2*x(1)*x(2)+2*x(2)^2+7;
end
```

Comment: OP already found the minimum just didn't realize that.